# Merging Data Frames based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames. One with a list of all mutations (+ a score associated), and another with a subset of mutations actually observed (+ a measured value).

I want to merge my second data frame (subset of observed) into my larger data frame (all possible) and bring with it the data that is associated with the observed mutations (fit values). However, when I do this, my merged data frame shows NaN for all the fit values.

The code I tried for merging is below, with samples of my data frames and the resultant output (as s1).

```
s1 = pd.merge(data_frame, data_frame_2, how='left', on=['position', 'mutation'])

    data_frame #all possible
position    mutation    A_score Normalized_A_Score
0   1   *   0.00    0.000000
1   1   A   849.69  100.007062
2   1   C   849.94  100.036486
3   1   D   849.76  100.015301
4   1   E   849.67  100.004708
5   1   F   849.00  99.925850
6   1   G   849.56  99.991761
7   1   H   849.83  100.023540
8   1   I   849.63  100.000000
9   1   K   851.51  100.221273
10  1   L   849.56  99.991761
11  1   M   849.63  100.000000
12  1   N   849.63  100.000000
13  1   P   849.00  99.925850
14  1   Q   849.13  99.941151
15  1   R   851.70  100.243635
16  1   S   849.15  99.943505
17  1   T   849.94  100.036486
18  1   V   849.63  100.000000
19  1   W   849.00  99.925850
20  1   Y   849.10  99.937620

data_frame_2 #observed
position    mutation    fit_val adjusted_fit_val
0   1   *   0.633847    0.274555
1   1   A   0.832698    0.473406
2   1   C   0.857012    0.497719
3   1   D   0.873119    0.513827
4   1   E   0.859805    0.500512
5   1   F   0.359053    -0.000239
6   1   G   0.786489    0.427197
7   1   H   0.876687    0.517395
8   1   I   0.820826    0.461534
9   1   K   0.886447    0.527154
10  1   L   0.868197    0.508905
11  1   N   0.909416    0.550124
12  1   P   0.843697    0.484405
13  1   Q   0.838892    0.479600
14  1   R   0.878175    0.518883
15  1   S   0.981739    0.622446
16  1   T   0.709694    0.350402
17  1   W   0.866746    0.507453
18  1   Y   0.876647    0.517355


    s1 #merged
position    mutation    A_score Normalized_A_Score  fit_val adjusted_fit_val
0   1   *   0.00    0.000000    NaN NaN
1   1   A   849.69  100.007062  NaN NaN
2   1   C   849.94  100.036486  NaN NaN
3   1   D   849.76  100.015301  NaN NaN
4   1   E   849.67  100.004708  NaN NaN
5   1   F   849.00  99.925850   NaN NaN
6   1   G   849.56  99.991761   NaN NaN
7   1   H   849.83  100.023540  NaN NaN
8   1   I   849.63  100.000000  NaN NaN
9   1   K   851.51  100.221273  NaN NaN
10  1   L   849.56  99.991761   NaN NaN
11  1   M   849.63  100.000000  NaN NaN
12  1   N   849.63  100.000000  NaN NaN
13  1   P   849.00  99.925850   NaN NaN
14  1   Q   849.13  99.941151   NaN NaN
15  1   R   851.70  100.243635  NaN NaN
16  1   S   849.15  99.943505   NaN NaN
17  1   T   849.94  100.036486  NaN NaN
18  1   V   849.63  100.000000  NaN NaN
19  1   W   849.00  99.925850   NaN NaN
20  1   Y   849.10  99.937620   NaN NaN
```

Why wont the fit_val or adjusted_fit_val column values from data_frame_2 show up when I merge the data frames together? Thanks for any help in understanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is different types of column `position` - string and integers:

```
data_frame['position'] = data_frame['position'].astype(int)
data_frame_2['position'] = data_frame_2['position'].astype(int)

s1 = pd.merge(data_frame, data_frame_2, how='left', on=['position', 'mutation'])
print (s1)
    position mutation  A_score  Normalized_A_Score   fit_val  adjusted_fit_val
0          1        *     0.00            0.000000  0.633847          0.274555
1          1        A   849.69          100.007062  0.832698          0.473406
2          1        C   849.94          100.036486  0.857012          0.497719
3          1        D   849.76          100.015301  0.873119          0.513827
4          1        E   849.67          100.004708  0.859805          0.500512
5          1        F   849.00           99.925850  0.359053         -0.000239
6          1        G   849.56           99.991761  0.786489          0.427197
7          1        H   849.83          100.023540  0.876687          0.517395
8          1        I   849.63          100.000000  0.820826          0.461534
9          1        K   851.51          100.221273  0.886447          0.527154
10         1        L   849.56           99.991761  0.868197          0.508905
11         1        M   849.63          100.000000       NaN               NaN
12         1        N   849.63          100.000000  0.909416          0.550124
13         1        P   849.00           99.925850  0.843697          0.484405
14         1        Q   849.13           99.941151  0.838892          0.479600
15         1        R   851.70          100.243635  0.878175          0.518883
16         1        S   849.15           99.943505  0.981739          0.622446
17         1        T   849.94          100.036486  0.709694          0.350402
18         1        V   849.63          100.000000       NaN               NaN
19         1        W   849.00           99.925850  0.866746          0.507453
20         1        Y   849.10           99.937620  0.876647          0.517355
```

Comment: Hm for some reason when I replicate that code exactly (after converting the data types to int).. I still get NaN values for all fit_val and adjusted_fit_val columns that were merged..